# Creating objects in a loop and using other objects as class constructors

Tags: java, class, object, for-loop, constructor

I'm very new to Java. I have to create a program that models an employee. This employee has an Employee Number, a First and Last name, an Address comprising of a Street, a City, and a State, and a hire date consisting of a month, a year, and a day. This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AssignmentTen
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println();
        int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int eNumber;
        String input2;
        String input3;
        String input4;
        String input5;
        String input6;
        int input7;
        int input8;
        int input9;
        int input10;

        Employee[] employee = new Employee[num]
        for (int i = 0; i < num, i++)
        employee[i] = new Employee()

        input2 = getString ("Enter Employee First Name:");
        input3 = getString ("Enter Employee Last Name:");
        input4 = getString ("Enter Employee Street:");
        input5 = getString ("Enter Employee City:");
        input6 = getString ("Enter Employee State (Initials):");
        input7 = getInt ("Enter Employee Zip Code (5 Digits):");
        input8 = getInt ("Enter Employee Hire Month (MM):");
        input9 = getInt ("Enter Employee Hire Day (DD):");
        input10 = getInt ("Enter Employee Hire Year(YYYY):");

        eNumber = getInt ("Enter Employee Number:");
        System.out.println("#" + eNumber);

        Name n1 = new Name(input2, input3);
        System.out.println(n1.firstName + " " + n1.lastName);

        Address a1 = new Address (input4, input5, input6, input7);
        System.out.println(a1.eStreet + " " + a1.eCity + " " + a1.eState + " " + a1.eZipCode);

        Date d1 = new Date (input8, input9, input10);
        System.out.println("Hire Date: " + d1.month + "/" + d1.day + "/" + d1.year);
    }

    public static int getInt(String paramString)
    {
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(paramString);
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }

    public static String getString(String paramString)
    {
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(paramString);
        return str;
    }
}

class Employee
{

}

class Name
{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    Name(String first, String last)
    {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
    }
}

class Address
{
    String eStreet;
    String eCity;
    String eState;
    int eZipCode;

    Address(String street, String city, String state, int zipCode)
    {
        eStreet = street;
        eCity = city;
        eState = state;
        eZipCode = zipCode;
    }
}

class Date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;

    Date(int eMonth, int eDay, int eYear)
    {
        month = eMonth;
        day = eDay;
        year = eYear;
    }
}
```

How can I make the Employee class use the Name, Address, and Date classes as constructors to store all of the employee's information in one object? Additionally, it is required I have a separate Employee, Name, Address, and Date class in my program. Also, how can I create a for loop that creates a number of employee objects equal to the num integer (which is entered from the command line) so that each object has their own Name, Date, and Address?

I know that this code will probably not compile, I just need to finish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Employee has an address, a name, and a hire date so you have to declare instance variable of type Address, Name and Date .Then you can write a constructor that takes Address, Name and Date as constructor arguments and assign them to Employee's instance variable

---

```
Class Employee{
    private Name name;
    private Address address;
    private Date hireDate;
    public Employee(Name name,Address address,Date hireDate){
           this.name = name;
           this.address = address;
           this.hireDate = hireDate;
        }
}
```

for loop

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[noOfEmployees]

for(int i = 0; i < noOfEmployees; i++){
    Name name = new  Name(String first, String last);
    Address address = new Address(String street, String city, String state, int zipCode);
    Date hireDate = new  Date(int eMonth, int eDay, int eYear);
    employees[i] = new Employee(name,address,hireDate);
}
```

where noOfEmployees is the number of employees you want to create.
and you can use java's inbuilt Date class java.util.Date for hireDate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a non-default constructor for your `Employee` class and permit your `Name`, `Address` and `Date` parameters to be associated with it by creating matching instance variables.

(In the code below you'd also have to create accessor methods for each field)

```
class Employee
{
  private Name name;
  private Address address;
  private Date date;

  public Employee(Name name, Address address, Date date)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.date = date;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "permit my Name, Address, and Date parameters to be associated with it?"

Comment: @user2709168 all I mean is that if you don't define instance variables for the Employee class, then instances of your other classes just exist "out there" and their relationship to the employee isn't encapsulated properly.